# Почему данный код выдаёт ошибку? Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let UserName = prompt("Кто там?");

if (UserName == "Админ") {
    let pass = prompt("Пароль?");

    if (pass == "Я главный") {
        alert("Здравствуйте!");
    } else if (pass == "" || pass == null) {
        alert("Отменено");
    } else {
        alert("Неверный пароль");
    }

   else if (UserName == "" || UserName == null) {
    alert("Отменено");
}  else {
    alert("Я Вас не знаю"); 
}
```

Comment: "else if (UserName"  -  перед  этим нужна закрывающая  }

Answer (score 1):

```js
let UserName = prompt("Кто там?");

if (UserName == "Админ") {
    let pass = prompt("Пароль?");

    if (pass == "Я главный") {
        alert("Здравствуйте!");
    } else if (pass == "" || pass == null) {
        alert("Отменено");
    } else {
        alert("Неверный пароль");
    }
} // здесь скобка пропущена 
   else if (UserName == "" || UserName == null) {
    alert("Отменено");
}  else {
    alert("Я Вас не знаю"); 
}
```